# Retrieve Data from Different Tables (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 4 tables in a SQL Server database with following schema:

1. **Attendance**

   ```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Attendance] (
   [AttendanceId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
   [CourseId]     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
   [StudentId]    UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
   [SubjectId]    UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
   [Semester]     INT              NOT NULL,
   [Month]        NVARCHAR (50)    NOT NULL,
   [Count]        INT              NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT [PK_Attendance] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([AttendanceId] ASC),
   CONSTRAINT [FK_Attendance_Student] FOREIGN KEY ([StudentId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Student] ([StudentId]) );
   ```
2. **Course**

   ```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Course] (
   [CourseId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
   [Name]     NVARCHAR (50)    NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT [PK_Course] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([CourseId] ASC)
   );
   ```
3. **Student**

   ```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Student] (
   [StudentId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
   [CourseId]  UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
   [Name]      NVARCHAR (100)   NOT NULL,
   [RollNo]    INT              NOT NULL,
   [Semester]  INT              NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT [PK_Student] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([StudentId] ASC),
   CONSTRAINT [FK_Student_Course] FOREIGN KEY ([CourseId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Course] ([CourseId])
   );
   ```
4. **Subject**

   ```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Subject] (
   [SubjectId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
   [CourseId]  UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
   [Name]      NVARCHAR (100)   NOT NULL,
   [Semester]  INT              NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT [PK_Subject] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([SubjectId] ASC),
   CONSTRAINT [FK_Subject_Course] FOREIGN KEY ([CourseId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Course] ([CourseId])
   );
   ```

I need to create a attendance report in the following format:

**Course Name** | **Student Name** | **Subject Name** | **Semester** | **Month** | **Count**

Please tell me what SQL Query I need to use and if there's any change in schema required then suggest the same.

I'm looking forward to have your replies.

Thanks,

Comment: I've tried the following query:

SELECT Course.Name, Student.Name, Subject.Name, Attendance.Semester, Attendance.Month, Attendance.Count FROM Course, Student, Subject, Attendance

The problem with this is it is retrieving all records from Student, Subject and Course tables but I want records only for subjects for which the attendance is stored.

Comment: Google about `SQL Joins`.

Comment: Thanks buddy, I've tried INNER JOIN and it led me to achieving the exact query I needed. Thanks for pointing out this aspect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `JOIN` in your query so that it only returns rows which match a `[StudentId]` from the Attendance table.

e.g.

```
SELECT c.CourseName, s.StudentName, u.SubjectName, u.Semester, a.Month, a.Count
FROM Student s 
    JOIN Attendance a ON s.StudentId = a.StudentId
    JOIN Course c ON a.CourseId = c.CourseId
    JOIN Subject u ON c.CourseId = u.CourseId
```

Something along these lines will only return rows which specifically match

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry but I didn't Vote Down buddy and thanks for your reply, it worked with a little adjustment. I'm marking it as Answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Can you also tell me how do I create a View from this Query?

Comment: read: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp - should be the same as creating view with any query

Comment: To create a view, use CREATE VIEW view_name AS SELECT xxx where xxx is your working SELECT statement